# inverter to rectifier

Tags: inverter, bridge-rectifier

I'm putting together an experimental geo resistivity measuring device following vague instructions found on the internet. I was wondering if it is safe to connect a Mastervolt AC MASTER 12/500 inverter to a MDQ 100A 1600V rectifier. Also I would like to know what approximate DC voltage would I obtain?

http://www.mastervolt.com/products/ac-master-12v/ac-master-12-500/
http://goldelectric.ca/download/MDQ.pdf

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will get about 320 volts DC from the rectifier.  A 30 Amp rectifier would be more than adequate, as the inverter can only deliver about 2 Amps.

Whether this is safe or not depends on how you wire things, and what you are doing with the 320 volts DC.

**230 Volts AC and 320 volts DC ARE DANGEROUS** if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks Peter! Both leads go directly to electrodes stuck in the ground, current through these is measured and used in a formula together with the voltage picked up from another pair of electrodes to give the apparent resistivity of the soil. I've used the inverter directly, but some people recommend DC rather than AC, and the higher the voltage the deeper you can prospect...